# Flash Player 10.1.102 slow loading flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash, flash-builder, flashplayer-10

I am currently working on a very large enterprise flex application.  The current code base is being built in Flex Builder 3 with the flex 3.4 SDK.  When the newest version of flash player was released we noticed that our application would take a much longer time to load or some users were unable to load the application at all.  This has been tested both in firefox and IE with the same outcome.  Seems like on newer machines which are more powerful the application will load only after a long period of time and on older machines the browser would just crash.

I have tried building with Flex Builder 3 and the 3.5 SDK however that still produces the same result.  I am going to try building with Flash Builder and 4.1 SDK mx only.

Has anyone run into an issue like this?  Does anyone have any other solutions I can try?

EDIT: The application runs fine on 10.1.53.64 but on version 10.1.102.64 I have the slow loading issue as stated above.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used the Flex Profiler to try to isolate any memory leaks / performance issues?  Without a code review, I think it's close to impossible to give you any specific advice.

Comment: And I voted to close, as I find this an overly broad question, with few details that would help us solve the issue.

Comment: The application works on an older version of the flash player without any issues.  The application is thousands of lines of code if not more, it would be impossible for me to provide code, not to mention the code is owned by my employer.

Comment: What size is the main swf file?

Comment: Also, have you tried it on different browsers and OSes?

Comment: Ive noticed a similar issue with Flex 3.2 on Flash 10,1,102,64 in Firefox. It may be a case that user's are requested to upgrade to a new version of flash. Also, if there its a big project, your going to hit some tricky problems with Flex 4 conversion, and the project will not work for your Flash 9 customers (i think)

Comment: We have tried on: Win - firefox/ie; osx 10.6 safari/firefox; Same issue results.

Comment: SWF file size is about 5mb.  Also I know the flex 4 conversion is going to be an issue I have already started looking into it.  I was hoping I could try a few different things first, the flex 4 conversion maybe a last ditch effort.

Comment: I also noticed today that when I have the debug version of 10.1.102.64 installed the application behaves correctly, I do not run into the slow loading issue.  I have the slow loading issue only when I am on the release version of the flash player.

Answer (score 0):

We run into similar problem in our project. While loading by itself isn't a problem in our case, instantiation of visual components takes much longer under SDK 4, 3-4 times.

It means that if your components get created all (or many) at once your Flash Player will be spending 3-4 more time initializing, and may eventually exceed timeout limit (which is indeed about a minute, not 15 sec).

You app my need a redesing, to split initialization into steps, reuse components, etc.

Here are some simple performance samples for MX and Spark to try:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/786472?tstart=30